# How do I assign a block template (.html) to a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, block-editor

I'm using WordPress 6.0 and I've created a child theme from TwentyTwentyTwo. I've created a custom post type using code like this:

```php
register_post_type('foobar', [
   'public' => true,
   'show_in_rest' => true, // enable block editor
   // etc
]);
```

In my child theme, I've created the directory `templates`, and within it, a file named `foobar.html`. I've copied the contents of `single.html` from `twentytwentytwo/templates/` to this folder and renamed it to `foobar.html` to make it match the custom post type.

If I open the site editor, and click "Templates", I see these templates listed:

- Single Post
- Page
- foobar
- Home
- Search
- etc...

However, when I create a new post of the custom post type `foobar` using the WordPress admin interface, the default template is "Default template", and not "foobar". How do I change the default block template for a custom block type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic and block(-based) themes both use the same [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), so for example in classic themes, we can add a template named `single-<post type>.php` which would be used as the default template for displaying single posts in a specific post type, and in block themes, the equivalent template is named `single-<post type>.html`, but that template must be placed in the `templates` directory (e.g. at `wp-content/themes/your-theme/templates`) as opposed to the theme's root directory in classic themes.

So you should rename your template to `single-foobar.html` and WordPress will automatically load it on single post pages in the `foobar` post type, e.g. at `https://example.com/foobar/foo-1/`.

However, to make it appear as the "Default template", e.g. in the "Post tab → Template panel" in the block editor's sidebar, you need to *register the template as a default template* using the [`default_template_types` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/default_template_types/):

```php
add_filter( 'default_template_types', 'my_theme_default_template_types' );
function my_theme_default_template_types( $template_types ) {
    $template_types['single-foobar'] = array(
        'title'       => 'Single Foobar',
        'description' => 'Displays a single foobar post.',
    );

    return $template_types;
}
```

Preview (WordPress v6.0.1):

[image: Preview image]

So I hope that helps and you should check the [Differences and similarities between classic themes and block themes](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/block-themes/#differences-and-similarities-between-classic-themes-and-block-themes), and you might also want to learn about registering custom templates: <sub>(which in classic themes, they use a header line, i.e. a PHP comment like `Template Name: Foobar`)</sub>

- https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/theme-json/#defining-custom-templates
- https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-json/#customtemplates

Comment: Thank you! That worked a treat. It was hard to find advice online for block themes as opposed to classic/legacy themes. This gave me the missing pieces.